# Translate this VB.NET LINQ statement to C#, having trouble

Tags: c#, .net, linq, vb.net-to-c#

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    Dim q = From f In System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families _
            Select f.Name
    ListBox1.DataSource = q
    ListBox1.DataBind()
End If
```

I'm new to [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), and I'm following a [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) tutorial, so I don't know LINQ in C#. How can this be translated to C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised none of the popular conversion sites support LINQ syntax (as far as I can tell)

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    var q = from f in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families select f.Name
    ListBox1.DataSource = q;
    ListBox1.DataBind()
}
```

Comment: lol Thanks Rex, I always recognize you from the avatar. Thanks again, bro! :D

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = from f in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families select f.Name;
```